# Is the correct response "here you are" or "here you have"?

Tags: responses

If the question is:

> Would you give me a leaflet in Russian, please?

Which answer is correct?

> Yes, here you are madam.

or

> Yes, here you have, sir.

Comment: Hello and welcome. A few of us are voting to move your question to [ell.se]. However, it would help if you could [edit] your question to explain what you've found so far.

Answer (score 2):

What is idiomatic is "Here you are" or "Here you go." I admit that the verb actually describing the specific situation described is "have," but these are idioms for saying in a friendly and casual way "This should satisfy your request." Idioms do not make literal sense. "Here you have" is not idiomatic. You could idiomatically say "Now you should have what you want," but to me it sounds very stiff and formal.

EDIT: I should have qualified that what I said above is limited to the U.S.

Comment: I think "here you are" or "here you go" are the idiomatic expressions in Brit Eng too.

Comment: In BrE one would also hear "There you go" and "There you are". If you think about it, both are very odd ways of saying "Here it is", which is what both formulations actually mean.

Comment: "Here you have" is not idiomatic anywhere on its own. "Here you are." is standard in all Englishes. I think one has to be careful not to overdo the AmE/BrE/AussieEng/etc. thing.

Comment: Lambie, Given that there are many variants of English that I do not know, I must restrict myself to those that I do. There are literally versions of what is called English that I find virtually incomprehensible, and I am not willing to pronounce personally on what is standard in every currently spoken variant of the language,

Answer (score 0):

In this context, you can say:

Here it is.

In informal English, you can say:

There you are.

Here you are.

There you go.

Here you go.

Though not incorrect, you usually don't use sir/madam with these idioms.

"Here you have" isn't idiomatic.

Comment: There  you go is very informal and would not be followed by madam or sir.